# PHP 7, Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I am building a login sequence for a website that I am designing for a school project with **MySQL** and **PHP7** (which I am relatively new to). I need some help understanding what this error means and how I can resolve the issue:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\login_tools.php on line 19

Here is the line of code for a function which ensures a login has succeeded and retrieves the associated user details:

```
function validate($dbc, $email=",$pwd=")
```

Comment: Replace each double quote with two single quotes.

Comment: Using $dbc, $email = '', $pwd = '' with the two single quotes instead of doubles quotes fixed the issue. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: FYI, the reason why you get this particular error message is that `",$pwd="` is an interpolated string, equivalent to `"," . $pwd . "="`. As this is a dynamic expression it can't be used as a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see by the line of code you posted you used a single double quote in the function declaration. If you look closely you'll see that ,pwd=" is all in red because of the single double quote after $email=

Either change the double quote to 2 single quotes or add another double quote.

```
function validate($dbc, $email='',$pwd='')
```

OR

```
function validate($dbc, $email="",$pwd="")
```

Answer (score 12):

I think an explanation of this error message is valuable since it's new to PHP 7 - Let's reframe this for clarity:

```
<?php

function validate($dbc, $email="$foo"){
}

?>
```

As a beginner, you probably would have found PHP 5.6's error message more helpful for debugging:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"' in
>   /home/hpierce/test.php on line 3

However PHP 7 displays the error you've found:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   /home/hpierce/test.php on line 3

When you declare an optional argument, as you have with `$email`, you are required to provide a literal value (a *"constant expression"*) that stands alone without needing to be evaluated (determined by using *"invalid operations"*). By including a reference to `$foo`, you've declared your optional argument by using a dynamic expression which isn't valid here.

Examples of providing constant expressions:

```
//Providing an integer literal
function validate($dbc, $email=1){}

//Providing a string literal
function validate2($dbc, $email="foo"){}

//Providing an array literal
function validate3($dbc, $email=Array("foo", "bar")){}
```

This rule applies to any situation where you need to define constant expressions, such as adding a class constant:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    //Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations
    const BAR = $bar;
}

?>
```

Comment: That's the correct answer here, thank your for the explanation